# global name 'get_serializer_class' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I understand I need to import it but where am I importing it from?

```
from rest_framework import get_serializer_class
```

The above doesn't work and I'm not seeing anything in documentation anywhere that's explaining where the function is being imported from.

For reference this is my view that's giving the error -

```
class CalendarDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            serializer_class = CalendarGETSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer_class = CalendarPUTSerializer
        return serializer_class

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        evntname = self.request.GET.get('name')
        queryset = Evntmst.objects.filter(evntmst_name=evntname)
        serializer = get_serializer_class(queryset)
        if queryset:
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            raise Http404

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = get_serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

edit - here is the Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  400.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  397.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Tidal\API\views.py" in get
  398.         serializer = get_serializer_class(queryset)

Exception Type: NameError at /deploy/calendartest/
Exception Value: global name 'get_serializer_class' is not defined
```

Comment: should it not be `self.get_serializer_class` as it is a class method ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd need to see a stacktrace to understand better where the error is coming from but I believe you don't actually need to import anything.

From this bit of documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#get_serializer_classself

it would seem you just need to override that method in the class you define as your api.

Your api class looks fine from what I can see at a glance

EDIT: after seeing the traceback it's a little more clear:

You should have

`self.get_serializer_class()(queryset)` where you currently have `get_serializer_class(queryset)`

Comment: thnx.  I've included the Traceback.